# AngularJS won't update view

Tags: angularjs

I'm just new to angularJS and have my first big problem.
First I wanted to create a list and update it, but it doesn't work.

```
// index.html
<form ng-controller="ListCtrl">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="listname" ng-model="listname">
        <input type="button" ng-click="set()" value="add new list">
    </div>
</form>
<div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="list in lists">
            {{list.id}} - {{list.listname}}
        </li>
    </ul>
    {{output}}
</div>
```

The fun part is the resetForm(), there I reset the form but also will try to update the $scope.output. But that output never changes, no matter what I try to change.

```
// ListCtrl
var ListApp = angular.module('ListApp', []);

ListApp.controller('ListCtrl', function ($scope) {
// add new records to database
$scope.set = function() {
    $scope.createTableIfNotExists();
    $scope.insertSql = 'INSERT INTO Lists (listname) VALUES (?)';

    if ($scope.listname) {
        $scope.db.transaction(
            function (transaction) {
                transaction.executeSql($scope.insertSql, [$scope.listname], resetForm);
            }
        );
    }
};

function resetForm() {
    // clear the input field
    $scope.listname = "";
    $scope.listForm.$setPristine();
    $scope.output = 'Hello World';
    $scope.$apply();
}
```

**Edit:**
When I try this with $apply the console shows me an error:

```
function resetForm() {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.listname = "";
        $scope.listForm.$setPristine();
        $scope.output = 'Hello World';
    });
}
```

And the error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

The error points direct to the start of "$scope.$apply(function..."

**Edit 2:**
When I add a new button in index.html and call a function with ng-click and in this function I just say

```
$scope.output = 'Hello World!';
```

Then my view updates. 
It will only not update when I use a callback to change the scope. Don't understand that. I thought everything is connected in angularJS, especially when I'm in the same controller.

**Edit 3:**
Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/qNwPpN)

Comment: you've got twice ng-controller="ListCtrl" in your index.html

Comment: @sylwester I'm not sure, but I think you can link the same controller to two different views.

Comment: I tested this with twice linked controller and it worked well.

Comment: Please show more codes. Where is the `listForm` defined? Where does the `set()` method get called?

Comment: @runTarm
I updated my original post. The set() method is called in the index.html with submit. What for more code do you need? This is simple angularJS structure.

Comment: I still couldn't see the `listForm` is defined anywhere. I'm wondering that it will produce an exception when run `$scope.listForm.$setPristine();`.

Comment: As for the 2nd `resetForm()` in the edited section, the `$scope.apply(` should actually be `$scope.$apply(`, notice a missing `$`.

Comment: @runTarm Ok I updated that missing "$" in $scope.$apply but it won't help here. The listForm, why has it to be defined? The form resets when I call it. The name listForm is the name of my formular. Do I need a definition or something for it?
But this doesn't have to do the my {{output}}.

Comment: Firstly, if the `listForm` isn't defined, the statement `$scope.listForm.$setPristine()` would throw an exception right before the `$scope.output = 'Hello World'` get called, so the `output` will never be touched. Secondly, yes, the controller can be reused in different places, but each place will have their own scope. Therefore, even if the `output` has been successfully set in the `resetForm` of the top controller, it will not affect the `output` in the bottom controller anyway.

Comment: Ok thx for the explanation. But I see no errors at all. Anyway I commented every unneccessary line to prevent it. So now my resetForm() only uses the output update. But again ... no change in the view. Grrrr ... :-(

Comment: I would suggest you put the codes into a plunker, so other people will be able to reproduce your issue and helps.

Comment: OK, I will try it and inform you when I'm ready.

Comment: plunker is added in the original post

Answer (score 1):

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

That's because you called `$scope.apply` instead of `$scope.$apply`.

Try calling it with a callback function:

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
    $scope.listname = "";
    $scope.listForm.$setPristine();
    $scope.output = 'Hello World';
});
```

Comment: That's better. Did you try the snippet I posted above?

Comment: No, it isn't mandatory to pass a callback into `$scope.$apply`, it can just be called `$scope.$apply()` without any exception regardless of it should be called like that or not.

Comment: @Tipo My mistake, you should call `$apply` instead of `apply`.

Comment: No problem I fixed it already. But that doesn't solve my problem. :-( I don't see my failure here. How can I see if I'm out of my scope? Maybe I'm not in the scope? But normally I don't believe it.

Comment: Ok the plunker is added in the original post